# Knockout data-bind disable. With two conditions

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Is it possible to use || operator in disable like this:

```
data-bind="click: createSubActivity, disable: isDeliveryHistory || isTimeAndMaterialLocked"
```

I have tried, but it seems like it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `isDeliveryHistory` and `isTimeAndMaterialLocked` are observables, you should use them like this:

```
data-bind="click: createSubActivity, disable: isDeliveryHistory() || isTimeAndMaterialLocked()"
```